# How to Migrate EML data in chuck to Google Apps Mail using Google API ver 2?

Tags: c#, email, eml, chunking

I am migrating EML mails to Google Apps.
When i try to Migrate a EML file with two attachment 2.1 MB and 1.96 MB.

It is throwing exception:

"The request was aborted: The request was canceled."

I am using below code:

```
MailItemEntry[] entries = new MailItemEntry[1];
String msg = File.ReadAllText(EmlPath);
entries[0] = new MailItemEntry();
entries[0].Rfc822Msg = new Rfc822MsgElement(msg);

........

MailItemFeed feed = mailItemService.Batch(domain, UserName, entries);
```

I think sending data can resolve this issue.So,how can send this EML data in chunk to Google Apps?

Thanx

Answer (score 1):

Just a thought, instead of using the Google's API if you use IMAP instead for the same purpose does it help?

The reason I am proposing it is because, I have had great success in archiving my official Microsoft exchange (200 MB) mailbox into my personal Google Apps mailbox (under a label) using Outlook connected through IMAP.

I am thinking maybe using the API has some kind of timeout issue either on the Google server side or on your c# code (did you check your socket timeout settings?)

Cheers!